# F# For each element in list a, apply function to elements in list b

Tags: f#

Given the following set of types representing a store:

```
type Article    = string
type Amount     = int
type Price      = int
type Desc       = Amount*Price
type Stock      = (Article*Desc) list
type Order      = Article * Amount
type Status<'a> = Result of 'a | Error of string
```

I want to make a function which takes an `Order` and a `Stock` and returns a `Status<Price * Stock>`. The value of the defined function below `get (a,k) st` is `Result (p,st')` where `p` is the price of `k` pieces of `a` and `st'` is the new stock obtained from `st` by removal of `k` pieces of `a`.

Example:

```
let rec get (a,k) st =
    match st with
    | (a',(n',p'))::rest when a'=a -> Result (p'*k,(a',(n'-k,p'))::rest)
    | (a',(n',p'))::rest           -> 
        match get (a,k) rest with
        | Result (price,stock) -> Result (price,(a',(n',p'))::stock)
        | Error e              -> Error e

get ("a2", 10) st
val it : int * (string * (int * int)) list =
  Result (200, [("a1", (100, 10)); ("a2", (40, 20)); ("a3", (25, 40))])
```

Now, how would I go about doing this if I took an `Order list`?

Such as `get [("a2",10);("a1",10)] st` would return `Result (300, [("a1", (90, 10)); ("a2", (40, 20)); ("a3", (25, 40))])`

Comment: Your `get'` code fails to compile with `Unmatched '['`

Comment: Fixed - butterfingers.

Comment: I don't understand how are the numbers in your expected output calculated. Should the subtraction happen for `a2`? And why `300`?

Comment: In the first example, the subtraction happens for `a2`, and we subtract `10` from `50` in `st` and multiply `20` with `10`, which is then put as the first element in the result. 

In the second example, with a `(string * int) list` as input, it is `300`, because we multiply `20` in `a2` with `10` and `10` in `a1` with `10`.

Comment: But you wrote `("a2",10)`

Comment: `get' ("a2", 10) st` with the original function, but what I'm attempting to do is being able to say `get' [("a2",10); ("a1",10)] st`, i.e. provide it a list, and get the result `(300, [("a1", (90, 10)); ("a2", (40, 20)); ("a3", (25, 40))])`.

Comment: @Khaine775 This is really confusing. Does the list represent something? That would help us understand what this is actually about :)

Comment: I understand. I've tried rewriting the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Article    = string
type Amount     = int
type Price      = int
type Desc       = Amount * Price
type Stock      = (Article * Desc) list
type Order      = Article * Amount
type Status<'a> = Result of 'a | Error of string
```

First, since you ask for an implementation of the function `get`, let’s rename the existing function `get` into `getArticle`.

```
let rec getArticle (a, k) st =
    match st with
        | (a', (n', p')) :: rest when a' = a -> Result (p' * k, (a', (n' - k, p')) :: rest)
        | (a', (n', p')) :: rest -> 
            match getArticle (a, k) rest with
                | Result (price, stock) -> Result (price, (a', (n', p')) :: stock)
                | Error e               -> Error e
        | [] -> Error "Article not in stock"
```

I also added an extra case to get rid of the “Incomplete pattern matches” warning.

**The answer to your question is `List.fold`.**

The first argument of `List.fold` is a folder function of type `'State -> 'ElementType -> 'State`. In this question, `'ElementType` is `Order`.

`getArticle` does pretty much what the folder function is supposed to do: compute the next state, when traversing one element —in this question: one order— in the list. But not quite:

- `getArticle` takes as input state a `Stock` but returns as output state a `Status<Price * Stock>`, in which the extra `Price` is the total price of the retrieved articles (so far). `List.fold` expects the input and output state of the folder function to be the same type.
- `getArticle` takes as first argument an element from the list —which in this question has type `Order`—, and as second argument the input state. `List.fold` expects a folder function that takes these two arguments swapped.

So, let’s constuct a folder function, in which the total price of the retrieved articles so far is accumulated (added):

```
let folder status order =
   match status with
       | Result (totalPriceSoFar, stock) ->
           match getArticle order stock with
               | Result (price, st) -> Result (totalPriceSoFar + price, st)
               | Error e -> Error e
       | Error f -> Error f
```

We’re practically done now.

The second argument of `List.fold` is the inital state — in this question: a `Result` with the initial stock and the total price so far initialised to `0`.

The third argument of `List.fold` is the list over which to iterate — in this question: the list of orders.

```
let get orders initialStock =
    let initialStatus = Result (0, initialStock)
    List.fold folder initialStatus orders

let initialStock = [("a1", (100, 10)); ("a2", (50, 20)); ("a3", (25, 40))]
get [("a2", 10); ("a1", 10)] initialStock
```

**Closing remark**

You chose to define the type `Stock` as `(Article * Desc) list`. Given that you use this list basically as a look-up map in which an article can’t have 2 prices or 2 amounts, why not choose `Map<Article, Desc>`?